Нужно вывести значения всех чисел от А до В, если B меньше А, вывести в обратном порядке
Написал код выдаёт только 4 теста из 6
A = int(input())
B = int(input())

if A >= B:
    for i in range(A, B - 1, -1):
        print(i, end = " ")



Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Выводит все числа от А до В. Если В меньше А, то выводит в обратном порядке
A = int(input('A: '))
B = int(input('B: '))

if A < B:
    for i in range(A, B + 1, 1):
        print(i, end = ' ')
else:
    for i in range(A, B - 1, -1):
        print(i, end = ' ')

Код с убиранием "дубликата логики вывода"
A = int(input('A: '))
B = int(input('B: '))

inc = 1
if B < A:
    inc = -1

for i in range(A, B + inc, inc):
    print(i, end = ' ')


Результат проверки программы
Выполнено 0% тестов.
cистема ругается

@ЯрославБелёв Скорее всего из-за форматирования вывода - поправил

не, что-то не так. Ошибку выдает

@ЯрославБелёв Даром ясновидения не наделен, хрустальный шар сломан, предсказатели в отпуске. Напишите ошибку, которую вам выдает и самое главное - кто выдает.

https://dropmefiles.com/7Ab0c
вот ссылка там файл

@SwaD, очевидно, что у него из-за лишних промтов не проходит. Но если он не может такое исправить, то не вижу смысла помогать.

@ЯрославБелёв, а если всё-таки подумать?

Думаю уже в районе полутора часов, если честно, не думается совсем

поэтому и зарегался на СО именно для этой задачи
до этого всё решал сам

@ЯрославБелёв Как вам можно помочь, если вы не пишите, что у вас за ошибки и где? Информацию из вас всем миром вытягивали клещами. Вот сейчас конкретно что за ошибка у вас? Напишите ее текстом.

Эта система не как обычный компеллятор, т.е. там нету ошибок как syntax или runtime. Там выполнение задач идёт по тестам (строчкам) и ошибка в 1 и 4

сайт silvertest

Если буквально трактовать условия задачи, то может оказаться лишним пробел в самом конце. Чтобы его не было - нужно собрать данные в список и распечатать как print(*result_list). Ну это опять же вариант гадания

@mrgervant, там в начале и вовсе не пробел.

@ЯрославБелёв Еще как вариант, попробуйте убрать из input вывод текста
